# Can an employer use discretion for furlough?

Tags: resignation, human-resources, united-kingdom, furlough

I left my job on 15/02/2020 (last payment date 25/02/2020) due to bullying which lead me to a nervous breakdown. Due to the state of my mental health this was something I decided on quite quickly and the company were happy for me to take this course of action as they felt it was the safest for my health and they could not resolve the issue quickly enough to keep me out of danger.

Then corona virus happened whilst I was between jobs.

I have contacted the old firm who have stated that as I wasn’t an employee as of 28/02/2020 I am not eligible for furlough. Is there any wiggle room on this date?

It’s likely there is nothing that can be done and this is all down to terrible luck and timing but I want to be sure I’ve tried everything I can.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what are the requirements of furlough, and what are the benefits of it that you need?

Answer (score 9):

> Employers can claim for furloughed employees that were employed and on
>   their PAYE payroll on or before **19 March 2020**. This means that the
>   employee must have been notified to HMRC through an RTI submission
>   notifying payment in respect of that employee on or before 19 March
>   2020.

https://www.gov.uk/government/news/furlough-scheme-cut-off-date-extended-to-19-march

> If you made employees redundant, or they stopped working for you on or
>   after 28 February 2020, you can re-employ them, put them on furlough
>   and claim for their wages from the date on which you furloughed them
>   through the scheme. This applies to employees that were made redundant
>   or stopped working for you after 28 February, even if you do not
>   re-employ them until after 19 March. This applies as long as the
>   employee was on your payroll as at 28 February and had been notified
>   to HMRC on an RTI submission on or before 28 February 2020. This means
>   an RTI submission notifying payment in respect of that employee to
>   HMRC must have been made on or before 28 February 2020

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/claim-for-wage-costs-through-the-coronavirus-job-retention-scheme

However, the Coronavirus Job Retention Scheme is for employees on furlough who will have a job to return to. As you left voluntarily, and are not returning to that employer, you are probably not eligible for the CJRS, and your employer might be making a false declaration if they 're-employed' you solely for the purpose of the scheme.

If you are not eligible for furlough payments you should look at claiming benefits from DWP.

https://www.understandinguniversalcredit.gov.uk/employment-and-benefits-support/making-a-new-claim/

Comment: Even covered universal credit, +1